# How to load a native API with JNA

Tags: java, maven, jna

I am developping in java for five years and I am also using Maven for almost five years.

I am currently working on a proximity chat project in order to get some knowledge about multi-threading, network, SourceDataline and TargetDataline. For bandpass optimization I need to find a way to encode the bytes array that represents a samples coming from the microphone.

I know that [Mumble](https://github.com/mumble-voip) already propose this technology but I want to do it by myself even if it will not be as efficient. In the wiki it is written that the software is based on [Audio codec](https://github.com/xiph/opus) which is written in C.

So that is the first time for me to use native code and therefore that is the first time I have to work with JNA.

**THE PROBLEM**: I am not able to load the library.

For flexibility, the all project is divided into several sub project listed here from the lowest layer to the higher:

communication: send/receive asynchronously byte from the network.
messenger: structure a message to send to the remote.

mumble-common: Gather the request a client can send to the remote or the server can send to each client. It depends on the projects *communication* and *messenger*.
sound: Simplify access to the microphone and speakers. It is **this project** that will integrate the dll in order to optimize the bandpass.

mumble-client: Package to send data to the server without knowing the message structure. It depends on the projects *mumble-common* and *sound*.

mumble-client-gui: It is the jar the final user use. It depends on the project *mumble-client*.

To work with audio codec in java, I found this [project](https://github.com/tbocek/opus-wrapper) which is a java wrapper for the native dll. I added this project as dependency for my *sound* project (Adding the repositories and dependency maven tag in the pom). However when I try to run the *mumble-client-gui* from the IDE, I got this error :

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Unable to load library 'opus': Native library (win32-x86-64/opus.dll) not found in resource path [resource path list]
```

Until now, this is what I tried :

- Update the class path of *sound* from Eclipse but first I got the same error and second I had to furnish a absolute path which is not what I want to do because the project will be deployed on several machines.
- Use maven-nativedependencies-plugin but I did not get a big changes.
- Integrate the dll directly in my *sound* project using JNA but it throws an exception because the dll is not registered in the class path.
- Copy/past the dll into a known Directory and load it using :

```
System.load("absolute/path/to/library")
```

but I got another exception : The dll is in 32 bit whereas the JVM is in 64 bit but the dll is **really** in 64 bit. For me that is a secondary issue if I can load and use the dll directly with JNA (using the already implemented java wrapper or using directly JNA and the dll manually).

So right now I have absolutely no idea of what I am missing..

The solution I am looking for should respects the following criteria:
It should works if *mumble-client-gui* is running from the IDE or from the jar and if I have to modify the resource path, I'd rather to precise a relative path.

Feel free to ask for more details and for source code ! :)

Here is the pom.xml of the sound project :

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>fr.pederobien</groupId>
    <artifactId>sound</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>sound</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
 
    <properties>
        <author>Pierre-Emmanuel41</author>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>Cp1252</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    </properties>
 
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>tomp2p.net</id>
            <url>http://tomp2p.net/dev/mvn/</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
 
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>fr.pederobien</groupId>
            <artifactId>utils</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.tomp2p</groupId>
            <artifactId>opus-wrapper</artifactId>
            <version>1.3</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
 
    <build>
        <finalName>sound</finalName>
        <sourceDirectory>src/main/java</sourceDirectory>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <targetPath>./src/main/resources/natives</targetPath>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
                <directory>${basedir}/src/main/resources/natives</directory>
                <includes>
                    <include>libopus.dll</include>
                </includes>
            </resource>
        </resources>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                            <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.2</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.0</version>
 
                <configuration>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                    <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>make-assembly</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>src</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>jar</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: DLLs go on the library path, not the class path. 
"The dll is in 32 bit whereas the JVM is in 64 bit but the dll is really in 64 bit." - How do you know for sure?  It seems unlikely that the JVM/OS would report this incorrectly.

Comment: Thanks swpalmer for answering so quickly ! I don't have the links anymore, but as far as I remember the dll came from an official site on which it was possible to download the dll in 32 bits and in 64 bits. I downloaded both of them to be sure and when I tried to load the 64 bits first. I got an error (I don't remember the message) but loading the 32 bit dll gave me this error "libopus.dll %1 is not a valid win32 application" and this message is different from the one I got when I tried to load the 64 bit dll.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need any maven configuration as that's mostly for the JVM itself and won't impact JNA's library loading.  You can configure the JNA search paths from Java, though, at your program start-up.

From the [JNA javadocs](http://java-native-access.github.io/jna/5.9.0/javadoc/com/sun/jna/NativeLibrary.html), you can set `jna.library.path` to the directory you want to search for all DLLs.  This will be searched in addition to platform-specific search locations for system DLLs.

```java
System.setProperty("jna.library.path", "your/path/here");
```

Alternately you could set a search for a specific library with [`addSearchPath()`](http://java-native-access.github.io/jna/5.9.0/javadoc/com/sun/jna/NativeLibrary.html#addSearchPath-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-)

```java
NativeLibrary.addSearchPath("opus", "your/path/here");
```

Comment: Thank you Daniel for answering.

I prefered using the second solution but I still got an error :

```
Exception in thread "" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Unable to load library 'opus':
Le module spécifié est introuvable. (3 times)
Native library (win32-x86-64/opus.dll) not found in resource path ([Paths list here])
 at com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary.loadLibrary(NativeLibrary.java:301)
```

I put the library in the folder "src/main/java/resources/win32-64-x86" so I wrote

```
NativeLibrary.addSearchPath("opus", "src/main/resources/win32-x86-64/opus.dll");
```

Comment: That error is usually associated with loading a 32-bit DLL from a 64-bit JVM, which you indicated in the second part of your question was a problem.  I see from your answer that you appear to have resolved this now.

Answer (score 0):

Okay based on the solution proposed by Daniel Widdis,

I put this code :

```
NativeLibrary.addSearchPath("opus", "src/main/resources/win32-x86-64/opus.dll");
```

into a static block of the *ExternalEncoder*, the class that will use directly the [java wrapper](https://github.com/tbocek/opus-wrapper/blob/master/src/main/java/net/tomp2p/opuswrapper/Opus.java). In that case the library is loaded only once.

It seems working because I don't get any error by now. But I found something strange that maybe you can explain to me :

I am using eclipse and when I save the *ExternalEncoder*, then in my folder "\target\classes" it creates the directory win32-64-x86 with the dll inside. When I delete it, remodify *ExternalEncoder* and save it, then the directory is recreated.

Where it comes from ? From Eclipse ? From Maven ? The win32-64-x86 directory name ?

Comment: This isn't really an answer to the question (different than what I suggested) and is a whole new question. Please ask a new question with those details; posting that question in an answer won't get any visibility.