# How to load native library and its transitive native dependencies with JNA?

Tags: java, jna

This comes up periodically but none of the answers work for me or are complete enough for me understand what is going on. For example, [How to load a native API with JNA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68974402/how-to-load-a-native-api-with-jna).
I can get the primary lib to load, but none of its transitive dependencies. I have a single native lib that I need to make an interface for but it has many native libraries on which it depends.
I have tried many variations of three approaches and not hit on the right combination.

1. native libs directly on the classpath with various directory structures ('darwin' or 'darwin_x86_64' in my case)
2. native libs in a jar, jar on the classpath, sytem variable jna.nounpack=false
3. native libs in a jar, jar is unpacked to a temp directory <tmp>, system variable jna.library.path=<tmp>

I set jna_load_debug=true.  I can see the main lib getting loaded but subesequent failure because transitive dependencies are not loaded and there is no indication that the correct places are being searched.

Here is some of the output from unpacking the native libs into a directory and setting jna.library.path

```
INFO: Adding paths from jna.library.path: /var/folders/cv/xl07kvgs0q91fv5w0x1y5mbh0000gn/T/snafu17797529543521833103
Sep 20, 2023 9:36:56 AM com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary loadLibrary
INFO: Trying /var/folders/cv/xl07kvgs0q91fv5w0x1y5mbh0000gn/T/snafu17797529543521833103/libstellarsolver.dylib
Sep 20, 2023 9:36:57 AM com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary loadLibrary
```

Nice! the temp directory containing the lib and its transitive dependencies is added to search path.

```
INFO: Loading failed with message: dlopen(/var/folders/cv/xl07kvgs0q91fv5w0x1y5mbh0000gn/T/snafu17797529543521833103/libstellarsolver.dylib, 0x0009): Library not loaded: @executable_path/../Frameworks/libcfitsio.4.dylib
  Referenced from: <ABEB0A7F-C1DB-3C8B-BB02-6A20D400CAAD> /private/var/folders/cv/xl07kvgs0q91fv5w0x1y5mbh0000gn/T/snafu17797529543521833103/libstellarsolver.dylib
  Reason: tried: '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/temurin-17.jdk/Contents/Home/Frameworks/libcfitsio.4.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/lib/libcfitsio.4.dylib' (no such file, not in dyld cache)
```

This indicates to me that libstellarsolver.dylib was found and JNA realizes it needs to find transitive dependency libcfitsio.4.dylib. There is this failure and others but there is never any indication that it looks in jna.library.path for this dependency. This is baffliing to me.

The stackoverflow question above suggests I might have to create an explicit search path for every transitive dependency. Can that be true? This seems like a commmon use case for JNA. Help is greatly appreciated.

Dave

Answer (score 0):

The issue seems to be that loading a library is passed from JNA to a native loader without a larger context. If the native loader fails, JNA does not take any steps to remediate that failure. The consequence is that the native loader must be given all the context it needs independent of JNA. This means setting environment variables used by the native loader. For Macs, these are `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` and `DYLD_FALLBACK_FRAMEWORK_PATH`.  See `man dyld` for more info.

My approach is to use these variables to specify where my app will unpack the native dependencies. Now both JNA and the native loader know where to find the dependencies.